# Using Rails & Devise with Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

This question is based on this tutorial http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js.

I don't know if I'm making a silly mistake or if the data-binding is just not working correctly. But when I login, I don't get the user's name - it defaults to "Guest" every time.

**Please see this gist that includes all the files associated:** https://gist.github.com/amaanr/5577152

I am running rails 4, ruby 2, ember-rails gem, and devise gem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the question is IMHO to opaque... please try to dissect the problem and point to the code in question, showing code examples of what you have tryed and what failed with what error and so on, so the probability that the community will be able to answer your question is somewhat higher, it's too easy to give some links and then ask to make it work :) I hope you get my point ...

Comment: Thanks @intuitivepixel, my error was that I didn't include the `//= require_tree ./initializers` in my app.js file. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

`//= require_tree ./initializers`

You need to make sure that you include the initializer folder in the rails asset pipeline.